# Wingpanel disappeared, and can't install

Tags: wingpanel

I just wanted to bring back my apps indicatiors, but when I used one of tutorials found on internet my Wingpanel just disappeared. I tried `killall wingpanel` and and `wingpanel` but terminal says `process not found` and `command not found`.
I also tried `sudo apt install wingpanel` and `sudo apt purge wingpanel` and then install again but it also doesn't work. Any solutions?

EDIT: I tried running `io.elementary.wingpanel` and I think this is it. But I got an error.

```
(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): io.elementary.wingpanel.notifications-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.227: NotificationEntry.vala:79: Unable to mask image: Failed to open file “/tmp/wingpanel-YWMDE1.png”: No such file or directory

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.337: g_object_new_is_valid_property: object class 'AyatanaCompatibilityMetaIndicator' has no property named 'display-name'

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:17:39.414: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.414: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.414: ((libnm-core/nm-connection.c:193)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:17:39.734: cannot register existing type 'AyatanaCompatibilityMetaIndicator'

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.734: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.734: g_object_new_valist: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:17:39.734: cannot register existing type 'AyatanaCompatibilityIndicator'

(io.elementary.wingpanel:21488): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:17:39.734: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
[1]    21488 segmentation fault  io.elementary.wingpanel
```

already tried to purge and install again but I get the same error.

Comment: Something is certainly very broken. Which version of Elementary are you using? Is there anything more specific in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to the source of the issue? The log you've provided doesn't have much to go on ...

Comment: @matigo after one hour of trying o fix it I deleted Pantheon by mistake, and then I decided to just reinstall my OS XD

Comment: That works 